# How to share images using share_plus plugin in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, share-plus

I am facing an issue to share image file from flutter app.

I have downloaded and saved the file to `directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` and the file is from firestore.

Now when I am trying to share the file its sending `BIN` file, how can I send it as Image ?

Here is the file path `/data/user/0/com.salegurusaller.leadsmarketing/app_flutter/Leads/products%2F1665586225384_rrxGbQjZd13dXzNjizM6_image_picker5704112476130713758.jpg?alt=media&token=37171ed7-d05c-439f-a693-39f2c6aac2cd`

Here is my codes while I am sharing the file using [share_link](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) plugin

```
Future shareSelected({required List<ProductImage> productsListForShare})async {
    if (productsListForShare.isNotEmpty) {
      final files = <XFile>[];
      for (var i = 0; i < productsListForShare.length; i++) {
        print(productsListForShare[i].photo!.path!);
        var xfile = XFile(productsListForShare[i].photo!.path!,);
        files.add(xfile);
      }
      await Share.shareXFiles(files);
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Share error", "Unable to share, there is some error");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it renaming the file while download. I was saving the file same as the url link now I have modified it with proper extension.

Previously I have saved my file as `/data/user/0/com.salegurusaller.leadsmarketing/app_flutter/Leads/products%2F1665586225384_rrxGbQjZd13dXzNjizM6_image_picker5704112476130713758.jpg?alt=media&token=37171ed7-d05c-439f-a693-39f2c6aac2cd`

Now I am saving it as `/data/user/0/com.salegurusaller.leadsmarketing/app_flutter/Leads/products%2F1665586225384_rrxGbQjZd13dXzNjizM6_image_picker5704112476130713758.jpg`

This resolved my issue